# in React-native, How to change the styles of NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, react-native

in react-native，how to change the styles of NavigatorIOS，such as backgroundColor?  thank you!

```js
var speedNews = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container} 
      initialRoute={{ 
        title: 'SpeedNews',
        component: ViewList
      }}/>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor : 'red', // it do nothing
    color : '#ffffff' // it do nothing
  }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

As far as I know, you can only change the following properties:

- **barTintColor**: The color of the background of the bar.
- **titleTextColor**: The color of the font.
- **tintColor**: The color of the buttons.

```html
<NavigatorIOS
  barTintColor='#000'
  titleTextColor='#fff'
  tintColor='#fff'
  initialRoute={{
    title: 'SpeedNews',
    component: ViewList
  }} />
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you change the font of the carrier, time and battery icons to white?

Comment: @JoshPinter There's a StatusBar component for that: <StatusBar
     barStyle="light-content" />. See more here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

Comment: @alfred Thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score -3):

maybe we can use "[react-native-router](https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router)"

Comment: This is not really an answer. If you successfully edit the style of your navigation component with React Native Router lib, edit your answer and post the code to do it. But if not, you should consider editing your question adding this link as a way to experiment.