# React Native iOS NavigatorIOS title font

Tags: ios, react-native

I am currently developing a React Native and I want to change the font of the NavigatorIOS title, I've found a few promising links from: [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2242) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600849/in-react-native-how-to-change-the-styles-of-navigatorios). However sadly neither have helped.

I currently have this code in my AppDelegate.m

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:22.0],
 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
}];
```

This also doesn't change the font of the title bar from the font the NavigatorIOS is given at the start.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put this code in `AppDelegate`.

Its better to put in an `RCT_EXPORT_METHORD` which should be called from any js class.

**In AppDelagete.h**

```
import BridgeModule.h
Add RCTBridgeModule protocol
```

**In AppDelegate.m**

```
Add:  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE() below implementation
@implementation AppDelegate
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
```

*Add this new function*

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(updateNavigationBar){

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:22.0],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]

}];

}
```

**Changes in js**

Add below lines

```
var AppDelegate = require('NativeModules').AppDelegate;

someJSFunction{

    AppDelegate.updateNavigationBar();

}
```

This Will Works. (Code just typed here)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the answer posted by [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3805771/rahul) will work due to the way React Native codes the Navigation Bar appearance changes.

I made a tiny patch that would allow your code to work. I may submit this to React Native, but haven't decided yet:

```
--- a/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTWrapperViewController.m
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTWrapperViewController.m
@@ -115,9 +115,11 @@ static UIView *RCTFindNavBarShadowViewInView(UIView *view)
     bar.barTintColor = _navItem.barTintColor;
     bar.tintColor = _navItem.tintColor;
     bar.translucent = _navItem.translucent;
-    bar.titleTextAttributes = _navItem.titleTextColor ? @{
-      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: _navItem.titleTextColor
-    } : nil;
+    if (_navItem.titleTextColor != nil) {
+        NSMutableDictionary *newAttributes = bar.titleTextAttributes ? bar.titleTextAttributes.mutableCopy :  [NSMutableDictionary new];
+        [newAttributes setObject:_navItem.titleTextColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
+        bar.titleTextAttributes = newAttributes;
+    }

     RCTFindNavBarShadowViewInView(bar).hidden = _navItem.shadowHidden;
```

With this patch, you should be able to do the following (Swift):

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Avenir-Light", size: 22.0) as Any]
```